# Uniform distribution in Ball with radius $\sqrt{n}$ is sub-gaussian

Tags: pr.probability

I have to show that a random vector $X$ who ist uniformly distributed on the Ball with Radius $\sqrt{n}$ is sub-gaussian with
$$\lVert X \rVert_{\psi_2}\leq C$$
I already know that the same result does hold for a random vector on the sphere with radius $\sqrt{n}$ (1).
I tried to show that $r Y$ is uniformly distributed on the Ball with Radius 1 for r uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and $Y$ uniformly distributed on the sphere with radius 1. Then I could use this to prove the claim in a similar way (1) is proved. However I am not sure if this is the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on the ball $B_{\sqrt n}$ of radius $\sqrt n$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Then
$$X=RY,$$
where $R:=|X|/\sqrt n$ and $Y:=\sqrt n\,X/|X|$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere $S_{\sqrt n}$ of radius $\sqrt n$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Note that $0\le R\le1$ and hence $E\exp\{c(X\cdot t)^2\}=E\exp\{cR^2(Y\cdot t)^2\}\le E\exp\{c(Y\cdot t)^2\}$ for all real $c>0$ and $t\in\mathbb R^n$. So, $\|X\|_{\psi_2}\le\|Y\|_{\psi_2}$.

Also, you know that $\|Y\|_{\psi_2}\le C$. Thus,
$$\|X\|_{\psi_2}\le C,$$
as desired.

Comment: Could you please explain how you get $\lVert X \rVert_{\psi_2} \leq \lVert Y \rVert_{\psi_2}$ from $E(X\cdot t)^2 \leq E(Y \cdot t)^2$?

Comment: @Hugo10T : Oops! I forgot to insert $\exp$. This is now fixed.